# @ Eclipse PyDev Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in did not match C++ signature:

Tags: python, c++, eclipse, pydev, boost-python

I am using a python plug in (PyOsmium) which use boost-python3 to compile C++. I can run the code in python shell from command line but got error message in Eclipse Photon.

```
h.apply_file(map)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    SimpleHandler.apply_file(ObjectCounterHandler, type)
did not match C++ signature:
    apply_file(SimpleHandlerWrap {lvalue} self, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > filename, bool locations=False, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > idx='sparse_mem_array')
```

I added this python3.6 path in pydev:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
```

but i just figured out that boost-python3 was installed in this folder: And also it was installed with brew. I just saw pip packages in the preferences>pydev listed.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0/lib
```

is this the problem? I've only tried to add this folder inside PYTHONPATH. I am not really sure what should I do since i am new with eclipse. I usually use atom with script package and it works there too.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am confused now. So the project that didn't run was actually initialized from new > pydev project. I just imported my project_folder from i was perviously working to eclipse and when i run identical code, it is working. So the problem is to be in PyDev project.

Comment: Is it working from the command line? Have you tried executing Eclipse from that same terminal (so that env vars are inherited)? I suggest you try to compare env vars from working to not working to try to diagnose what's wrong. See: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#MyProgramDoesNotWorkInPyDev